# I would like to know how to label all the points with directlabels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, direct-labels

I want to add labels with *direct.labels* to my plot of Gower's residuals (used in suitability analyses). I found, however, that the *direct.labels* function only adds labels to certain points and not to all of them. I wonder if there is a function that can do so using *direct.lables* or maybe someone can recommend me a better method to do so.

Thanks

Here is the code I am using

```
#Loading the data frame "R" to be used with ggplot
R <- read.csv(header=T, text='
Sector,Group,Type,Value
SBF,1,Residual,0.03
SBF,4,Residual,-0.06
SBF,5,Residual,-0.02
SBF,6,Residual,0.07
SDF,1,Residual,0.13
SDF,4,Residual,-0.08
SDF,5,Residual,0.08
SDF,6,Residual,0.03
SPF,1,Residual,0.04
SPF,4,Residual,0.16
SPF,5,Residual,-0.11
SPF,6,Residual,-0.08
SOF,1,Residual,0
SOF,4,Residual,0.16
SOF,5,Residual,0.32
SOF,6,Residual,-0.48
SSF,1,Residual,0
SSF,4,Residual,-0.06
SSF,5,Residual,0.01
SSF,6,Residual,0.2
SCO,1,Residual,-0.21
SCO,4,Residual,-0.06
SCO,5,Residual,0.07
SCO,6,Residual,0.2
SMA,1,Residual,0.28
SMA,4,Residual,-0.04
SMA,5,Residual,-0.17
SMA,6,Residual,-0.07
SNT,1,Residual,-0.11
SNT,4,Residual,-0.01
SNT,5,Residual,0
SNT,6,Residual,0.13
')
## Converting integers into factors so i can make groups of sectors 
R$Group<-factor(R$Group)
install.packages("directlabels")
library(directlabels)
## Creating p for the direct.labels function using ggplot
p<-ggplot(data=R, aes(x=Group, y=Value, group=Sector, colour=Sector))+
geom_text(aes(label=format(Sector),
            size=3,
            hjust=-0.2,
            vjust=-0.05),
        show_guide=FALSE)+
geom_segment(aes(xend=Group),yend=0,colour="grey50",linetype="solid")+
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0), linetype="solid")+
geom_point(size=3)+
scale_x_discrete(labels=c(
"1"="Group 1",
"2"="Group 2",
"3"="Group 3",
"4"="Group 4",
"5"="Group 5",
"6"="Group 6"), 
expand=c(0.13,0.05))+
scale_y_continuous()+
theme_bw()+
theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_text(size=13,
                             face="bold", 
                             hjust=0.5),
    axis.text.y=element_text(size=10,
                             face="bold", 
                             hjust=0.5))
direct.label(p,dl.combine(first.qp,last.qp))
```

Comment: For example. `direct.label(p, method = "bumpup")`  would label all points, and bump them up, if necessary, to avoid collisions.

Comment: Thanks Luke, it actually work fine for my data.